# How to send Dictionary and File with ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

In my html code I have one file (without form tag)

```
<input id="file1" type="file" class="form-control form-exception">
```

and a few textbox

```
<input id="id-one" type="text" class="form-control" >
<input id="id-two" type="text" class="form-control" >
...
<input id="id-six" type="text" class="form-control" >
...
```

Codebehind in C#

```
public class Model
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; set; }
        public string File { get; set; }
}

 public ActionResult Send(Model myModel)
{
...
}
```

I would like to send data from html to my controller: Id, `Dictionary<html id,html value>` and File.

This solution didn't work:

```
var dict={
  '[0].Key':'id-one'.
  '[0].Value':'aaaaa'
}
var data = new FormData();
data.append('Id', @Model.Id);
data.append('Fields', dict);
data.append('File',$('#file1')[0].files[0]);

 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Send")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            complete: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (response) {
            }
        });
```

This code work fine for file, but not for dictionary

How can i solve this? Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add objects to `FormData` using `.append()`, only simple values. You need to add each name/value pair individually.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('Id', @Model.Id);
data.append('Fields[0].Key', 'id-one'); // add the dictionary key
data.append('Fields[0].Value', 'aaaaa'); // add the dictionary value
data.append(File, $('#file1')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    ....
});
```

I assume you actually want to post the value of the input with `id="id-one"`, in which case its `data.append('Fields[0].Value', $('#id-one').val());`

In addition, as noted in Chris Pratt's answer, your posting the value of file input, so your property in the model should be

```
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to do so?

```
var dict={

  '[0].Key':'id-one'.
  '[0].Value':'aaaaa'
}
var data = new FormData();
data.append('Id', @Model.Id);
data.append('Fields', dict);
data.append('File',$('#file1')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Send")',
  data: data,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: The same effect: File is ok, but dictionary is a null

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues here.

1. Your `File` property must be of type `HttpPostedFileBase`, not `string`. The posted value will be a stream containing the actual file data, not something like the path on the client's filesystem (which would do you no good anyways).
2. Your text inputs currently have no name attributes, so their data will not be included in the post at all, let alone bound.
3. To bind to a dictionary, you must post both `Key` and `Value` members for each item, which necessitates two inputs for each item.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="Fields[0].Key" value="1" />
   <input type="text" name="Fields[0].Value" />

   <input type="hidden" name="Fields[1].Key" value="2" />
   <input type="text" name="Fields[1].Value" />

   <!-- etc -->
   ```

**EDIT**

Just noticed the updated code in your question. It seems the problem with binding to `Fields` is simply that you're not including the property name. In other words, `Fields[0].Key`, rather than `[0].Key`:

```
var dict={
    'Fields[0].Key':'id-one'.
    'Fields[0].Value':'aaaaa'
}
```

Comment: Property Name in dict didn't help. I tried this, still Field is a null. This is my  the biggest problem.